# Has something changed with what the "Return to Merchant" displays?

Tags: html, paypal

Does anyone know if something has changed recently with how PayPal handles the return values?

When someone purchases something from our site, they used to see something like "Return to Business Name". But for the past couple of weeks, they see "Return to person@website.com". This confuses them because they are expecting to be returned to a confirmation page where they can either download PDF files or just see "Thank you for your purchase." The weird thing is that clicking the person@website.com link takes them to the correct page, but most people don't try it because it looks like an email address.

Our button code hasn't changed:

`<!-- Return URL Values. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.test.com//Success.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.test.com/index.htm">`

The code also contains the following:

`<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="person@website.com" />`

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Sam